# MongoDB: How to populate an embedded reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm unsure of how would I populate the `questions` field in the `examBoard` collection in the following example (I have made my example reasonably complicated on purpose so I can properly understand how it works).

examBoard schema:

```
var topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    questions:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"question"
        }
    ],
});

var moduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    topics: [topicSchema]
});

var examBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    modules: [moduleSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("examBoard", examBoardSchema);
```

question schema:

```
var partSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mark: Number,
    content: String
});

var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    mark:Number,
    methods:[[partSchema]]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("question", questionSchema);
```

How I thought I should do it:

```
examBoard.find()
    .populate
    ({
        path:"modules.topics.questions",
        model:"question"
    })
    .exec(function(err,exam)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Failed to populate");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("exam[0].modules[0].topcis[0].questions\n"+exam.modules[0].topcis[0].questions);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Exam
  .find()
  .exec()
  .then((exams) => {
    // Populate questions
    Exam
      .populate(exams, {
        path: 'modules.topics.questions',
        model: 'question'
      })
      .then((populatedExams) => {
        // Do something with populated exams
      });
  });
```

Comment: When you write "Exam", are you referring to "examBoard" (since that is what it is called when it is exported)

Comment: Yes, that is. `Exam = mongoose.model("examBoard", examBoardSchema);`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there any documentation surrounding how you did this you could link me to? At the bottom of my question I have put how I originally thought I should do it, any documentation that explains how that method was wrong would be great.

Comment: Well, you encountered an infamous Mongoose [bug](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/601). However, since there is a workaround, I think they haven't patched it yet. You can find out more about Mongoose population` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), specifically at "Populating an existing document" part.